# Calculate average amount for each value between two columns

Tags: sql

I have this table called **ltv**

| tick_lower | tick_upper | ltv_usdc | ltv_eth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 204800 | 204880 | 38470 | -30.252800179 |
| 204620 | 205420 | 1107583.610283 | 867.663698001 |

The problem is that `ltv_usdc` and `ltv_eth` is distributed equally between `tick_lower` and `tick_upper`. So, I aim to return a table where ltv will be calculated for each tick.

Here is an example of calculations for the first row in the above table.

| tick | ltv_usdc | ltv_eth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 204800 | 38470/(`tick_upper`-`tick_lower`) = 480.875 | -30.252800179/(`tick_upper`-`tick_lower`) = -0.37816000223 |
| 204801 | 480.875 | -0.37816000223 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 204880 | 480.875 | -0.37816000223 |

Finally, I'm willing to group all the rows for each tick.

So far I haven't found a solution.

Comment: Don't spam DBMS tags. You'll attract the attention of people unable to help you, and waste your and their time. Update your post with one DBMS tag, the one you're currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in a few steps:

1. Get the max ticks (`tick_upper-tick_lower`) in `ltv`
2. Generate a number series from `0` to `max_ticks`
3. Calculate all `tick`s for each row in `ltv`
4. Aggregate `ltv_usdc` and `ltv_eth` to `tick`

Tested in MySQL 8 [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DSEg1BBh)

```sql
with recursive cte_param as (
select max(tick_upper - tick_lower) as max_ticks 
  from ltv),
cte_n (i) as (
select 0 as i
 union all
select n.i + 1
  from cte_n n
 where i < (select max_ticks from cte_param)),
cte_ltv as (
select tick_lower,
       tick_upper,
       ltv_usdc / (tick_upper - tick_lower) as ltv_usdc,
       ltv_eth  / (tick_upper - tick_lower) as ltv_eth 
  from ltv)
select l.tick_lower + n.i as tick,
       sum(l.ltv_usdc) as ltv_usdc,
       sum(l.ltv_eth)  as ltv_eth
  from cte_ltv l, cte_n n
 where l.tick_lower + n.i <= l.tick_upper
 group by tick
 order by tick;
```